# CMake fails due to missing protobuf-config.cmake while compiling project using Emscripten

Tags: c++, cmake, protocol-buffers, emscripten

I'm trying to compile to WASM a C++ project that has `protobuf` as a dependency. To this aim, I downloaded the precompiled library from the [protobuf-wasm](https://github.com/dsyer/protobuf-wasm) repo's releases and modified the project's CMake configuration so that it will point to the directory containing Protobuf's WASM version. To do this, I modified the call to `find_package()` so that it now contains the path to the directory where I have the WASM version:

```
 find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED PATHS /home/osboxes/protobuf-wasm)
```

The problem is that when I invoke `CMake` it fails because it can't find `protobuf-config.cmake`:

```
$ emcmake cmake -G Ninja -DWITH_CASTOR=OFF -DCMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH=ON ..
configure: cmake -G Ninja -DWITH_CASTOR=OFF -DCMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH=ON .. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/osboxes/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/cmake/Modules/Platform/Emscripten.cmake -DCMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING_EMULATOR=/home/osboxes/emsdk/node/16.20.0_64bit/bin/node
Using Ninja as default generator on Unix. If you wish to generate Makefiles instead, clear the build directory and use
    cmake -DNO_DEFAULT_GENERATOR=True -G'Unix Makefiles'
Using infra   config files from directory /home/osboxes/core-master/config/local
Using project config files from directory /home/osboxes/core-master/config/projects/gum
SYSTEM NAME:
Emscripten
CMake Error at cpp/ext/protobuf/CMakeLists.txt:72 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Protobuf" with any
  of the following names:

    ProtobufConfig.cmake
    protobuf-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Protobuf" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Protobuf_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "Protobuf" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/osboxes/core-master/wasm/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
emcmake: error: 'cmake -G Ninja -DWITH_CASTOR=OFF -DCMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH=ON .. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/osboxes/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/cmake/Modules/Platform/Emscripten.cmake -DCMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING_EMULATOR=/home/osboxes/emsdk/node/16.20.0_64bit/bin/node' failed (returned 1)
```

If I knew where to find one of those files, I could update CMake's configuration, but the archive with the precompiled WASM Protobuf doesn't contain those files. How can I fix this issue? I already tried compiling `protobuf` from source as explained in the repo's readme, but unfortunately [it didn't work](https://github.com/dsyer/protobuf-wasm/issues/2).